# Code::Blocks и CMake - запускаемый проект по умолчанию

Tags: c++, c, ide, cmake, codeblocks

Продолжая знакомиться с `Code::Blocks` возник вопрос по связке его с `CMake`.
Как в `CMake` назначить запускаемый проект по умолчанию ?

Структура проекта: библиотека и тест к ней, по умолчанию, после генерации `CMake` конфигов он не добавляет запускаемый проект, хотя макросы прописаны, и для `MSVC/MSVS` это работает:

```
set_property( DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} 
     PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT ${app_target}
)
```

предполагаю что макрос должен быть для `Code::Blocks`..

Без этого, при попытке запустить проект, `Code::Blocks` сообщает: `You must select a host application to "run" a commands only target`

Как сделать руками, очевидно:

[image: CodeBlocks target run default]

но хочется автоматизировать этот процесс.